# Logstash mutate filters

Tags: field, logstash

In my logs i am able to see database password.I want to remove the fields when ever it matches to one particular method.Below is the sample log format.

**Date=2016-02-23:00:36:29:242, Level=INFO , class=abc_class, method=abc_method, line=266, name=dataSourceUser, message=returning Property, value=password**

below is the sample logstashclient filter am using but still am able to see value field(password)

```
filter {
    grok {
            match => {"message"=>"Date=(?<LogTime>%{YEAR:Year}-%{MONTHNUM:Month}-%{MONTHDAY:Day}:%{TIME:Time}), (Level=)(?<SeverityLevel>[A-Z]*)(\s)?, %{GREEDYDATA:message}"}
            break_on_match => false
    }
    date {
            match => ["LogTime", "YYYY-MM-dd:HH:mm:ss:SSS"]
            target => "@timestamp"
    }
    if[method=="abc_method"]{
        mutate {
            remove_field => ["%{Value}"]
        }
    }
```

ETA : when ever it matches to method=abc_method it should not pass value field,for other metods it should pass

Comment: Gsub solves the issue :

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
remove_field => [ "value" ]
```

Comment: we can use gsub filter: gsub => [ "message", "value=%{Value}", "" ]

Comment: remove field just remove the field from passing.In my case i need value field ,but should be masked

Comment: Then use mutate->replace to change the value of the field.

Answer (score 0):

found the answer we can use gsub filter

eg :
 gsub => [ "message", "value=%{Value}", "" ]

Comment: You said you wanted "to remove the fields".  You're not removing a field, but removing part of the [message] field.

Comment: Yeah instead of removing field we can mask the value.Means we can hide the actual value that is present.